# Canadian Business Visa Refusal — why was I refused and what can I improve in a future application?

Tags: visas, canada, visa-refusals, applications

I've applied for business visa to Canada online on April 2016 to attend a10 days training on office furniture. I've provided all the documents they stated on their check list and after approximately 45 days from the date of submission, they refused my application and served me with refusal letter as attached.

I don't really know why they refused the application although I've submitted a detailed letter from my employer stating that they'll cover all the cost of travel. I even submitted a translated copy of my property contract along with my application as well as my family residency cards to prove that I have ties to Saudi Arabia.

I've submitted the following documents along with my application:

- full application
- copy of my old passport
- original current passport
- original employment letter stating my position, salary and length of employment (3.5 years)
- copy of my property contract
- copies of my family residency cards
- 6 months bank statements
- 6 months stamped salary slips

Does anyone have a clear explanation regarding this refusal?

[image]

Comment: Can you edit the question to include your status in SA, the length of your proposed trip, the purpose of the trip, and the duration and nature of your employment in SA, as well as an account of any evidence you may have submitted to demonstrate these?

Comment: I have zero competence in matters arising under Canadian law; but I can offer my own reaction to your refusal notice if that of any use at all.

Comment: Purpose is probably ticked because why is your company sending you to Canada for training on "office furniture"? That seems a rather odd thing.

Comment: The company that I work for is a local dealer for the mentioned Canadian company. The company in Canada hold dealers training every six months on the new released product, so I think its pretty normal to send an employee to attend the training.

Comment: @Gayot Fow, yes you can offer your own reaction as It might be useful to my case.

Comment: @Mohamed, ok, before starting can you describe your immigration status in your country of residence?

Comment: I legally work full time for my sponsor ( my sponsor is the company I'm working for). I already submitted an employment letter stating that along with my salary slips for the last 6 months.

Comment: Is the Canadian company holding group training? Either way, a letter from them detailing the training schedule might be useful.

Comment: Already submitted this letter along with my application, and they still refused it.

Comment: @Mohamed How much of that 3.5 years have already elapsed?  Or is your employment has indefinite duration?  How long before your Residence cards expire?